# Why is an "alignment exception" thrown when accessing an unaligned uint16 array with a pointer but not when accessing the array using subscripts?

Tags: arrays, pointers, exception, memory-alignment, memory-access

I will use the following code to explain my question:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed))
{
    uint8_t  var;
    uint16_t array[3];
}struct_t;

uint8_t frame[] = {0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xAB, 0xCD};

volatile struct_t *ptr = NULL;
volatile uint16_t *u16ptr = NULL;
volatile uint16_t a;
volatile uint16_t b;

//******************************************************************************************
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ptr = (struct_t*)frame;
    u16ptr = ptr->array;

    a = ptr->array[0]; // <---- NO Memory Access Exception here 
    b = *u16ptr;       // <---- Memory Access Exception here!
}
```

In that piece of code, I have forced `array` to be memory unaligned to have the memory access exception.

So my question is, **why is an "alignment exception" thrown when accessing the unaligned uint16 array through a pointer but not when accessing the array using array subscripts?**

None of the resources I've found so far explains why is this if both lines `a = ptr->array[0];` and `b = *u16ptr;` are accessing the exact same unaligned memory.

Could someone please explain or point in the right direction?

Comment: `u16ptr ` is a pointer to an aligned `uint16_t`, but you assigned to it a pointer to an **unaligned** `uint16_t`. If you turn on warnings, the compiler will tell you about your mistake: `warning: taking address of packed member of 'struct <anonymous>' may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]`

Comment: Maybe the compiler has some logic to generate unaligned access code when directly naming a member of a packed struct, and doesn't apply that logic to general pointer access

Comment: suggest adding a language tag BTW

Comment: @RaymondChen why is u16ptr a pointer to an aligned uint16_t?

Comment: Because that's how you declared it.

Comment: @RaymondChen does that mean that I would have to use the '__attribute__((aligned(X)))' to declare the pointer as 'unaligned'?

Comment: gcc doesn't seem to have a way to declare a pointer to an unaligned primitive. You need to [wrap the primitive inside a packed struct](https://www.alfonsobeato.net/arm/how-to-access-safely-unaligned-data/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting to read a 16-bit value from an unaligned address will trap on some architecutres.  Although the Standard defines the behavior of `x[y]` as equivalent to `*((x)+(y))`, which would cause an array to be decomposed into a pointer and then fetch a value from that address (trapping if the address isn't aligned), both clang and gcc treat `structOrUnion.memberArray[index]` as an lvalue that identifies part of a member of `structOrUnion`, as opposed to an expression that decomposes `structOrUnion.memberArray` to a pointer, forgets where the pointer came from, and then indexing that.

If the `[]` operators are used directly on an unaligned array which a member of a "packed" struct, or on any aarray-type member of a union, clang and gcc will do what they need to do to access the storage in question.  If, however, such an array is decomposed to a pointer, neither clang nor gcc will reliably allow it to be used to access an object of its type.

Comment: @RaymondChen: The reason the access of `ptr->arr[0]` works, despite `ptr->arr` being an unaligned address, is that neither clang nor gcc process `ptr->arr[0]` by taking the address of `ptr->arr` and attempting to fetch a 16-bit value from there.  Instead, they treat that as "load item 0 from an array of `uint16_t` *that is part of a packed structure*".

Comment: are you saying that the compiler will "somehow fix" ptr->arr[0] to make it work?

Comment: @m4l490n: On platforms that don't support unaligned loads/stores, the compiler will generate two byte-wide loads or stores to process the upper and lower halves of `ptr->arr[0]` separately.

Answer (score 0):

If a member of a structure or union is packed and therefore does not have its natural alignment,
then to access this member, you must use the structure or union that contains this member. You
must not take the address of such a packed member to use as a pointer, because the pointer might
be unaligned. Dereferencing such a pointer can be unsafe even when unaligned accesses are
supported by the target, because certain instructions always require word-aligned addresses.